# Terraform, error creating aws_iam_role_policy, string required

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm creating a aws_iam_role_policy with terraform with this policy:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "ecs_task_execution_role_policy" {
  name = "${local.environment}-${local.workload_name}-ecsTaskExecutionRole_policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.id
     
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ssm:GetParameters",
        "ssm:GetParametersByPath"    
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "${data.aws_ssm_parameter.datasource_password.arn}",
        "${data.aws_ssm_parameter.datasource_username.arn}",
        "${data.aws_ssm_parameters_by_path.all_parameters.arns}"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
EOF
}
```

I get this error:

```
data.aws_ssm_parameters_by_path.all_parameters.arns is list of string with 611 elements
 
Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

I know the data.aws_ssm_parameters_by_path.all_parameters.arns is a list of string but I need to create the policy with this arns, how can I do it?

Comment: The error is about `data.aws_ssm_parameters_by_path.all_parameters`, yet you haven't provide the code for it. Its unclear thus what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think you want to concatenate the existing `data.aws_ssm_parameter.datasource_password.arn`, `data.aws_ssm_parameter.datasource_username.arn`, and probably whatever is inside of the `data.aws_ssm_parameters_by_path.all_parameters.arns`. However, it has 611 elements, so not sure if that would even work.

Comment: I need to create the policy to allow the role to get parameters of the arns I give. Two are strings I get with the data, but the thitrd is a list because I need the role can get the 661 parameters. My issue is how can I do it, if I can convert the list of string in some single string because I don't want to add one by one all the 661 ssm parameters

Comment: You don't need to add them manually. I am telling you there is a limit on the number of characters a policy can have. Either way, you can try this:       `"Resource": "${concat([data.aws_ssm_parameter.datasource_password.arn], [data.aws_ssm_parameter.datasource_username.arn], data.aws_ssm_parameters_by_path.all_parameters.arns)}"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is a data source in terraform which enables you to write IAM policies using HCL, it is much more human-readable than trying to fit it into a JSON like in the question. So my suggestion would be to try the following:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_task_execution_role_policy" {
  statement {
    sid = "GetSSMParameters"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ssm:GetParameters",
      "ssm:GetParametersByPath"      
    ]
    resources = concat([data.aws_ssm_parameter.datasource_password.arn], [data.aws_ssm_parameter.datasource_username.arn], data.aws_ssm_parameters_by_path.all_parameters.arns)
  }
}
```

Note that there is a [limit on the number of characters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_iam-quotas.html#reference_iam-quotas-entity-length) a policy can have. Then, to create the policy, you would just do the following:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "ecs_task_execution_policy" {
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_task_execution_role_policy.json
}
```

In the last step, you would attach this policy to the ECS execution role, but that part of the code is missing from the question.